# Used an arraylist in Java to find four consecutive letters in a dictionary, error while building the code

Tags: java, arrays, string

This is the initial challenge I'm trying to address
1) takes two arguments—a “source" English word in a string, and an English dictionary supplied in an array
2) returns a list of English words as an array

The words returned are those from the dictionary that have four consecutive letters (or more) in common with the “source” word.  For example, the word MATTER has the four letters in a row “ATTE" in common ATTEND.

**The code however gives me errors with the substring**

Below is the code for your reference.

```
public class FourLetterInCommon {


    static String wrd = "split";
    static String[] d = new String[]{"SPLITS", "SPLITTED", "SPLITTER", "SPLITTERS", "SPLITTING", "SPLITTINGS", "SPLITTISM", "SPLITTISMS", "SPLITTIST", "SPLITTISTS"};

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(fourletters (wrd, d));
    }  

    public static List<String> fourletters (String word, String[] dict){
        int dictsize = dict.length;
        int wordlength = word.length();

        List<String> Commonletters = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i = 0; i<=dictsize; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<=wordlength;) {

                if(dict[i].contains(word.substring(i, 5)))
                {
                    Commonletters.add(dict[i]);
                }

                break;
            }

        }
        return Commonletters;
    }
}
```

This is the error message I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source) at FourLetterInCommon.fourletters(FourLetterInCommon.java:22) at FourLetterInCommon.main(FourLetterInCommon.java:10)
```

What does the errors mean? Apologies, but a bit clueless at this stage.

Comment: This code is giving me an error, sorry if it wasn't clear if(dict[i].contains(word.substring(i, 4)))
            {
                Commonletters.add(dict[i]);
            }

Comment: And the error is...

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
 at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
 at FourLetterInCommon.fourletters(FourLetterInCommon.java:22)
 at FourLetterInCommon.main(FourLetterInCommon.java:10)

Comment: Please don't include it as a comment.  Please edit the question to include it instead.

Comment: The second parameter to `substring()` is not the length of the substring. **Read the documentation** to learn what it actually is: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Please, restate your question more clear. As I understand, you want to get all the words form string array that have 4 letters from the given word("split" for example). Right? Letters don't have to be in the same sequence as in the given word. What about duplicate letters?

Comment: @SergeiSirik Yes, you're absolutely correct. Duplicate letters is ok, as far as it can find similar letters to the source word. I have edited my initial question to give a better understanding of the problem. I've got the structure right unfortunately with errors.

Comment: @JoeC Thanks  a ton for the input, I've corrected the query to better reflect the problem being faced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a few issues here.

1)

```
for(int i = 0; i<=dictsize; i++) {
```

should be

```
for(int i = 0; i<dictsize; i++) {
```

2)

```
for (int j=0; j<=wordlength;) {
```

should be

```
for (int j=0; j<=wordlength-4; j++) {
```

3)

```
if(dict[i].contains(word.substring(i, 5)))
```

should be

```
if(dict[i].contains(word.substring(j, j+4)))
```

4)

I don't believe you really want to `break;` there. I'm guessing you want to break when you find a match, so it should be inside the if statement.

Corrected code:

```
public class FourLetterInCommon 
{
    static String wrd = "SPLIT";
    static String[] d = new String[] { "SPLITS", "SPLITTED", "SPLITTER", "SPLITTERS", "SPLITTING", "SPLITTINGS",
            "SPLITTISM", "SPLITTISMS", "SPLITTIST", "SPLITTISTS" };

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(fourletters(wrd, d));
    }

    public static List<String> fourletters(String word, String[] dict)
    {
        int dictsize = dict.length;
        int wordlength = word.length();

        List<String> Commonletters = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < dictsize; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= wordlength - 4; j++)
            {
                if (dict[i].contains(word.substring(j, j + 4)))
                {
                    Commonletters.add(dict[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return Commonletters;
    }
}
```

Output:

[SPLITS, SPLITTED, SPLITTER, SPLITTERS, SPLITTING, SPLITTINGS, SPLITTISM, SPLITTISMS, SPLITTIST, SPLITTISTS]

Comment: I tried that, but as an output all I got was this: [] - Just the square brackets

Comment: [] indicates an empty list. Let me edit the answer to list the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

The following line would throw an `Exception`:

```
if(dict[i].contains(word.substring(i, 5)))
```

Here, `i` ranges from `0` to `dict.length` which is 10 in this case. `word` contains 5 characters only. So, accessing any character from index `5` onwards would throw an `Exception`.

If you want to check for certain number of characters then you should use this:

```
for (int j=0; j < wordlength;) {
        if(dict[i].contains(word.substring(j, wordlength - j)))
```